# Reduce the size of empty unity project android

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, filesize

I am working on a android game project with unity engine (version 5.2.0f3).
My question is:
an empty compiled project is 18 Mb APK file size.
Why and how can I reduce the size ?

Comment: I think you cannot. These 18 mb are all required by engine.

Comment: nope i saw someone did it but she do not wanna tell me !!!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do is Strip Byte Code, Use .NET 2.0 Subset, Set Script Optimization to "Fast but no exceptions", Vertex Compression to "Everything", and optimize mesh data.

In 5.3.2f1 it has more options, but in 5.2.0f3 I think it has a few of those mentioned above.

This is located under Player Settings, Other Settings, very bottom.

[image: Screenshot of Optimization Settings under Other Settings]

Comment: Hi ApolloSoftware, your answer would be okay if the OP wasnt tanking about EMPTY project compiled to apk. Your suggestion would work with project that contains scripts and meshes.

Comment: Sorry Jerry, but micro mscorlib would reduce the size. This directly affects the DLLs bundled in the APK.Also API compatibility level .NET 2.0 Subset would reduce sizes for a vanilla unaltered project. Both of those adversely affect file size. The rest of the settings, you are correct about! But not those aforementioned. Since DLL's are included despite assets or none!

Comment: on chante mon frere!